# Automated clearing /tmp using QGIS batch processing?

Tags: qgis, raster, linux, qgis-modeler

I'm currently batch processing a bunch (~200 x 200MB) of ascii grid surfaces using some SAGA and GDAL algorithms in QGIS and have been running into "out of storage" errors. The issue is that between runs of the model, the /tmp folder fills up after 7-8 surfaces are processed. Performing an "rm -r /tmp/*" between runs clears up space to restart the model. The /tmp folder isn't abnormally small (4g).

I'm not sure how unorthodox it would be to have QGIS send a command between runs to clear the /tmp folder but I'm curious to know how this could be automated (perhaps in python?) to run at the end of a model run. Any other solutions for processing lots of grids would be welcome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a **custom script** in your model to clear the '/tmp' folder at the end of each run. There's numerous ways to delete files but I like to use [shutil.rmtree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree) which deletes all files/folders in a specified directory.

To do this, go to *Processing Toolbox > Scripts > Tools > Create new script* and copy the following (adjust the path):

```
import shutil

shutil.rmtree('/tmp')
```

Save the script into `C:/Users/You/.qgis2/processing/scripts` (again, adjust path as I use Windows). Then add the custom script from the list of algorithms to your model. To add it at the end of the model, check the image:

[image: Model]

Now when you run your model in a batch process, it should clear the '/tmp' folder after each run.

Comment: That's fantastic! I had no idea that you could add custom scripts into the model-builder. Thanks!

Comment: @TrevorJ.Smith - Most welcome buddy! Haha yeah, it's pretty useful to add custom scripts when you have some idea how they work :). Hope it works for you!